# Different accounts not linking

Tags: bug, status-completed

I can not seem to get enough reputation to get chat to work. I think it is that my MO and SENetwork accounts aren't properly linked. In fact, my other stack exchange accounts aren't merged with my MO account either. I am assuming this is work in progress. Even so, it is curious that my MO and SENetwork accounts seem to be merged but I can not make MO my parent site, it simply does not show up as an option. My only options are Meta SO and SENetwork.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can certainly clear this up for you, would you mind getting in touch with me [via this form](https://mathoverflow.net/contact/other)? We can identify the various accounts, have you do a quick update to two profiles just to confirm ownership and then I can get them merged properly.

Please leave a comment for me when you've read this and filled out the form (just point to this meta post if you like) and I'll jump into that mailbox to take care of it.

Comment: Thanks! Form submitted.

Comment: Thanks for everything!